# How to add categorical column from existing column (Categorical Data in Python)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am having a excel sheet with Date, Label , Topic, Description and Link columns.
Here the Label field is related to Topic field as shown below:

#Head

```
| Label | Topic          |
|-------+----------------|
|   0   | Death          |
|   1   | Disaster       |
|   2   | Marriage       |
|   3   | Government work|
|   4   | Sports         |
|   5   | Politics       |
|   6   | Bill           |
|   7   | Religion       |
```

I want to automatically create the Label field from the Topic field from the Pandas data frame.
Can you help in creating the label field?

[1]: The excel sheet link is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jEgc6vTj50QFDjEUrZJojydCKlircJ9vY-n22jXPt_Q/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function to map the Topic to label using the dictionary.

### main.ipynb

```py
import pandas as pd

dictionary = {
    "Death": 0,
    "Disaster": 1,
    "Marriage": 2,
    "Government Work": 3,
    "Sports": 4,
    "Politics": 5,
    "Sports": 6,
    "Religion": 7
}

s = pd.Series(["Death", "Disaster", "Religion", "Sports", "Marriage"])
df = pd.DataFrame(s)

df["label"] = s.map(dictionary)

df.head()
```

#### Output

```sh
>>>
    0      label
0   Death      0
1   Disaster   1
2   Religion   7
3   Sports     6
4   Marriage   2
```